# Altering RoadClass Driving Directions for Walking Network in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

I'm using ArcGIS 10 Network Analyst Extension to try and incorporate their driving directions functionality into a walking network. I am wondering if there is any way to alter the RoadClass Values to be more suitable for a Walking Network. For example:

**RoadClass Value**: 3

**Type of Road Class**: Ramps

**Example**: Take ramp and go on US-59 N

Is there any way that I can modify or add a RoadClass value to be "Stairs" and instead of saying "Take ramp..." it says "Traverse stairs..." or "Elevators" saying "Use elevator"?

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43967/how-to-indicate-a-change-in-transport-mode-for-directions-in-a-multimodal-datase). It seems like we are working on similar projects as when I search for a question, you seem to have asked it a few months prior to me. Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: @Arabella Yes! In fact I JUST got answers from ESRI regarding RoadClass values for pedestrian networks in 10.1. You have to output directions as a GP tool, and select the NA Campus style. Then, the RoadClass values below will work.

12-Stairs
13-Escalators
14-Elevators
15-Pedestrian ramps

If you want to read the whole thread discussion it can be found here: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/76035-NA-Campus-directions-questions.

Comment: Excellent! Will try that out asap.

Comment: I think you should write up your comment as an answer.