# How to indicate a change in transport mode for directions in a multimodal dataset

Tags: arcgis-10.1, network-analyst, direction, multimodal-network

When I solve a route and generate directions for my multimodal dataset, the end product is not very user friendly:

[image]

The pedestrian started walking along Main Street and then boarded a bus to travel along the various segments of the bus route. Is there a way to change the text so that it makes more sense, so something like:

1. Walk northwest along Main St
2. Board the bus at Stop 1
   ...etc

The connectivity is set up so that the pedestrian can only get on the bus at official bus stops.

Comment: If you don't get any answers you might consider posting this to the [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/) site and/or submitting it as an enhancement request through ESRI support.

Comment: Looking at the slides from the ESRI UC technical workshops, it seems that using the `RoadClass` attribute as a descriptor might work. I'll try it out and post back here if it works.